# Why am I recieving InvalidComObjectException from MS Test unit tests, but only on the build server?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, tfs, mstest

I have a compatibility later project which happens to make calls to COM, for which I have some unit tests. When I run these tests from my local machine, everything goes just fine.

But when these tests run on my team's build server, I receive the following error:

> Class Initialization method
>   Foo.Bar.Baz.Initialize
>   threw exception.
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.InvalidComObjectException: COM object
>   that has been separated from its underlying RCW cannot be used..

I've seen some discussion about this kind of problem for previous versions of Visual Studio, around the 2005-2008 timeframe. But the unit test infrastructure was completely replaced in the 2012 timeframe. Most of the solutions seem to involve editing a ".testsettings" file, which this project does not have.

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 for development, and the build server and TFS instance are running TFS 2010 SP1.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was that the TFS 2010 Team Tools on the build server were using the Visual Studio 2010 testing bits.

I created a `.testsettings` file with the following content, and checked it in to TFS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Local" id="2010983b-bdae-4cf9-910d-08bad14e68cf" 
              xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>This forces tests to run as a MTA. (Visual Studio 2012 just works;
               2010 completely explodes on the build server)</Description>
  <Deployment enabled="false" />
  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific />
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
    <ExecutionThread apartmentState="MTA" />
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```

Note that I did not actually add this file to my unit test project itself in Visual Studio 2012. Then, I configured the build server's build definition to point to this checked in `.testsettings` file.

This way I get to use the new (better) test runner from Visual Studio 2012 on my dev box, but the Visual Studio 2010 test runner works just fine on the build server.

Comment: Hmm, having this test fail like that when the client thread runs as STA is very unhealthy.  MTA just hides that problem since it forces COM to create a thread to give the COM server a safe home.  Real code very often runs as STA.  And should for single-threaded COM servers.

Comment: @Hans: I have real code that calls the tested code from STAs and MTAs which works fine. Something MSTest is doing (e.g. running AssemblyInitialize on a thread different than the thread running individual tests?) is causing the failure.

Comment: @Hans: What kinds of cases could result in these kinds of failures? I'm not doing any threading related things in the test code.